# vue3.x how to use v-html in jsx

Tags: vuejs3

```
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
     newText = '<p>How are you?</p>'
    })
    return () => (
      <div>
        <div domPropsInnerHTML={state.newText}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

domPropsInnerHTML  render nothing, so vue3 how to use v-html in jsx

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/vuejs/jsx/issues/179) with `domPropsInnerHTML` not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `v-html` directive directly.